# Alternative Vector Styles

Tags: here-api

Are there alternative vector styles available for the Javascript API or all that we have is the default "normal" style?  I know that the Tile API does have several styles available - I like the "reduced" one, but I'd prefer to work with vectors.  I suppose I could use the style editor and make my own yaml file, but that's a lot of variables to tweak.

I'd like to style the map in very light colours or in grayscale so that my markers are more visible.  Is there a global style I could change for that?

Answer (score 0):

JS 3.1 API gives you all flexibility in terms of map styles. You can use the Map Customization Tool https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/. However, for now  only normal.day is currently offered from HERE.

To have an idea, we have also published an example on GitHub how to have a dark theme on the map. Here is the link:
https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/tree/master/change-style-at-load

Style looks like this: https://github.com/heremaps/maps-api-for-javascript-examples/blob/master/change-style-at-load/data/dark.yaml